# How to add last second into date?

Tags: sql, oracle

is it possible to add such a thing as last second of the day into date?

Let's say that I have dates with different times and I need every date set to time 23:59:59...

Is it possible?

Thanks

Comment: +1 day -1 second is the logic I'd follow to get that

Comment: It's usually better to model continua like time as semi-open intervals, with an inclusive start date and an exclusive end date. This tends to reduce the type of mistakes that can be made when comparing times (e.g. by accidentally excluding items that should have been included in a particular range but weren't because they occurred at 23:59:59.363)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
update the_table
   set the_date_column = to_date(to_char(the_date_column, 'yyyy-mm-dd')||' 23:59:59', 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss');
```

Comment: Well, it works but do we like to see string manipulation of structured data? I'd _guess_ that this would be slower, but you seem to be more experienced in Oracle and SQL in generic than me. Would this be quicker than the direct date manipulation I proposed? I'm a bit perplexed, as I have to admit that this is better readable, which is favorable, and from that perspective, my approach is premature optimization...

Comment: @ppeterka66 There is no "string manipulation" going on. I'm creating a new date value based on existing value (and this is "NLS" safe due to the format masks being use). But I like your idea just as well. It would be interesting though whether your version is faster - although I doubt it. The CPU required to do this will be much less compared to the I/O necessary to write the changes to disk.

Comment: On a second thought, the question of performance is not very relevant, unless it is proven to be a bottleneck. But readability is in fact crucial when maintaining an application. And one would have to pause and think about what my own solution does.

Answer (score 6):

In case the [solution proposed by @a_horse_with_no_name](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18916694/1667004) proves to be slow, it should be possible to do it this way:

+1 day -1 second is the logic I'd follow to get that result, without string concatenation:

```
SELECT trunc(SYSDATE) + 1 - (INTERVAL '1' SECOND) FROM DUAL
```

[SQL fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/d41d8/17563)

Translated into UPDATE

```
UPDATE MY_TABLE 
SET MY_DATE_COLUMN = trunc(MY_DATE_COLUMN) + 1 - (INTERVAL '1' SECOND)
```

**However** Keep in mind that maintainability is of key importance regarding writing software, and reading this is much harder than the other solution proposed.

## Recommended Reading

- [TRUNC](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/functions209.htm)
- [INTERVAL](http://psoug.org/definition/INTERVAL.htm)

Answer (score 0):

Yes. The data column can store date values including the timestamp with second values. Use it like this -

```
insert into tab_name
(dt)
values
(to_date('20/09/2013 17:50:50', 'DD/MM/YYYY HH24:MI:SS'));
```

Answer (score 0):

If it's an Oracle DATE datatype, you can take advantage of the following equivalences:

One second = 0.00001

One day minus one second = 0.99999

e.g.

```
UPDATE mytable
SET mydatecolumn = TRUNC(mydatecolumn)+0.99999
WHERE ...;
```

As for readability, once everyone has memorized just these two numbers, it becomes second nature to read something like `dt+0.99999` as "1 day less 1 second". YMMV.