# Previous Weekdays

Tags: sql, oracle, date-arithmetic

I have a requirement in which i have to find start and end date.
Start date is First sat of the previous month of created date and end date is previous friday of created date. 
Eg Below .. I am passing created date and need to derive start and end date like this below.

```
CREATED_DT            Start_date        end_date
04/08/2015 15:36      04/07/2015 00:00  31/07/2015 23:59
07/07/2015 15:32      06/06/2015 00:00  03/07/2015 23:59
```

Comment: Please go through http://stackoverflow.com/tour and accept the answer as answered which solved your problem.

Answer (score 1):

You should not depend on the **locale-specific NLS settings**.

You could use following functions:

- **NEXT_DAY**
- **ADD_MONTHS**
- **TRUNC**

For example,

```
SQL> alter session set nls_date_format='DD/MM/YYYY HH24:MI:SS';

SQL> WITH t(created_dt) AS(
  2  SELECT to_date('04/08/2015 15:36','DD/MM/YYYY HH24:MI') FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  3  SELECT to_date('07/07/2015 15:32','DD/MM/YYYY HH24:MI') FROM DUAL
  4  )
  5  SELECT CREATED_DT,
  6    NEXT_DAY(TRUNC(add_months(created_dt, -1),'MM') -1,TO_CHAR(to_date('6','J'),'Day')) -1 start_date,
  7    NEXT_DAY(TRUNC(created_dt, 'MM')      -1, TO_CHAR(to_date('5','J'),'Day')) -1 + 0.99999 AS end_date
  8  FROM t;

CREATED_DT          START_DATE          END_DATE
------------------- ------------------- -------------------
04/08/2015 15:36:00 04/07/2015 00:00:00 31/07/2015 23:59:59
07/07/2015 15:32:00 06/06/2015 00:00:00 03/07/2015 23:59:59

SQL>
```

To get the time portion as `23:59:59`, you could either add `0.99999` or subtract **INTERVAL '1' SECOND**. For example,

```
SQL> alter session set nls_date_format='DD/MM/YYYY HH24:MI:SS';

Session altered.

SQL> WITH t(created_dt) AS(
  2  SELECT to_date('04/08/2015 15:36','DD/MM/YYYY HH24:MI') FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  3  SELECT to_date('07/07/2015 15:32','DD/MM/YYYY HH24:MI') FROM DUAL
  4  )
  5  SELECT CREATED_DT,
  6    NEXT_DAY(TRUNC(add_months(created_dt, -1),'MM') -1,TO_CHAR(to_date('6','J'),'Day')) -1 start_date,
  7    NEXT_DAY(TRUNC(created_dt, 'MM')      -1, TO_CHAR(to_date('5','J'),'Day')) - (INTERVAL '1' SECOND)  AS end_date
  8  FROM t;

CREATED_DT          START_DATE          END_DATE
------------------- ------------------- -------------------
04/08/2015 15:36:00 04/07/2015 00:00:00 31/07/2015 23:59:59
07/07/2015 15:32:00 06/06/2015 00:00:00 03/07/2015 23:59:59

SQL>
```

Comment: Just need to add `0.99999` to the end dates to get the time as 23:59.

Comment: @JeffreyKemp Ah! I missed to see the time portion. Corrected, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Use Next_day function. The Oracle/PLSQL `NEXT_DAY` function returns the first weekday that is greater than a date.

```
select TO_DATE('04/08/2015 15:36' ,'DD/MM/YYYY hh24:mi') as created_date,
    next_day(ADD_MONTHS(TRUNC(TO_DATE('04/08/2015 15:36','DD/MM/YYYY hh24:mi')+1,'MM'),-1),'SATURDAY')
    as start_date,
    next_day(trunc(TO_DATE('04/08/2015 15:36','DD/MM/YYYY hh24:mi')-8)+0.99999 ,'FRIDAY')as end_date
     FROM DUAL
```

Instead of adding `0.99999` we can also achieve same thing with `1-(1/(24*60*60))` we are adding one day after that subtracting `1` part from `24*60*60` seconds.

Comment: Thanks Tarun but the end date which is coming is truncating the time stamp as well. it should be 23:59:59 .

Answer (score 0):

You can use some of the `Date` functions. I'm giving for `sysdate`. Use according to your requirement.

```
select NEXT_DAY(trunc((trunc (add_months (sysdate, -1), 'mm')), 'MONTH')-1, 'Saturday') as Start_date,
       NEXT_DAY(SYSDATE-8, 'FRIDAY') as End_date 
from dual;
```

Output

```
START_DATE  END_DATE
04-JUL-15   21-AUG-15
```

Comment: Thanks .. But the end date which i was expecting is till 23:59:59 .. that is not coming. Any idea how to take it

Comment: Refer this [Question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18916625/how-to-add-last-second-into-date/18916694#18916694). U just need to add `+0.99999`

Answer (score 0):

I have achieved by this way

end date: Where created _dt is date value what i am passing..!!

```
 next_day(TRUNC(to_date(created_dt,'DD-MM-YYYY HH24:MI:SS'))-7,'FRIDAY') + 
 INTERVAL '23:59:59' HOUR TO SECOND AS range_end_dt
```

Comment: Why are you applying to_date() to a date column?